# Upload files to Google Cloud Storage using FTP client

Tags: google-cloud-storage, ftp-server

I'm bit new to Cloud Storage.

We have an application which uploads files to our FTP server.

Now as our system grows, we would go for Cloud Storage service like Google Cloud Storage.

The main issue is our client software is already distributed to thousands of customers. This client software uploads file with FTP commands.

Now if we plan to change our storage to Google Cloud Storage, is it possible to upload file using FTP commands from our client software to Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running an FTP server on top of a directory mounted with gcs-fuse:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

Comment: How do you run the FTP server on top?